# Listening to uevents

Tags: android

I am  writing a system service which will listen to a custom uevent triggered by kernel and then send a custom intent to user space. In user space, an application will filter that intent and do some processing.
Somebody help me on application side.
I have created my own uevent but stuck in intent part.

Comment: what you have tried?/

Comment: i have tried pendingIntent.
Also i am inheriting Binder for my system service since my service does not do anything except transporting uevent from kernel to user space in the form of intent]

Comment: Good what is the result.. is it working?

Comment: yeah at some level..but i want to know if there is another way to achieve the same without using pendingIntent.

Comment: i think pending intent should work. may be some issue in your code .. look this http://raulherbster.blogspot.in/2015/06/uevents-in-android-from-kernel-events.html

Comment: yeah i checked..thanks
Is there any other way to notify in user space about uevent apart from system service ?

Comment: i dot know much,  but  think no